# Как защитить страницы от пользователей, которым они не принадлежат (Vue / Firebase)?

Tags: vue.js, firebase, vue-router

На проекте у каждого пользователя есть личный блог с адресом .../:id/
Все данные хранятся в firebase.
Как сделать так, чтобы личный блог мог просматривать не только зарегистрированный пользователь (сделал гард через vue router), но и тот кому он принадлежит. Хотелось бы сделать переадресацию на главную, если пользователь зашел по чужому адресу. Какое есть решение?